# How can I print specific element

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How can I print only the second element from the following output?

```
"java.exe","7184","RDP-Tcp#20","2","231,440 K","Running","CAB\27","0:00:59","start-app"
```

So basically I would like to get only “7184”

This is the script that I am using:

```
 @ECHO OFF

  echo Stoping the Application ...
    echo.
 tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "start-app"
```

Thank you

Comment: This can be done with a `FOR` loop. Use the `FOR /?` command for documentation. There are -MANY- examples of FOR loops on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a batch file you can get like this :

```bat
@echo off & color 0B
echo(
echo Stopping the Application ...
@for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "start-app"') do (
    echo %%a & Taskkill /PID %%a
)
pause
```